# Bibliography not being numbered

Tags: bibliographies

I'm currently finishing my master thesis, I'm using my school's thesis template. 
Everything goes fine, except for one thing - my citations in the Bibliography are not numbered.

That means in the PDF my bibliography looks like this

[image]

I spent more than 2 hours trying to fix this, but I was unable to.
I tried searching for any sign of supressing the numbering of my bibitems, but couldnt find any.

My bibliography looks like this

```
\bibitem{Mielach2013}
MIELACH, David. Americans Spend 23 Hours Per Week Online, Texting. \textit{Business News Daily} [online]. 2013, 2.7.2013 [cit. 2014-11-15]. Dostupné z: \url{http://www.businessnewsdaily.com/4718-weekly-online-social-media-time.html}

\bibitem{emarketer2013}
Digital Set to Surpass TV in Time Spent with US Media. \textit{EMarketer.com} [online]. 2013, 1.8.2013 [cit. 2014-11-15]. Dostupné z:
\url{http://www.emarketer.com/Article/Digital-Set-Surpass-TV-Time-Spent-with-US-Media/1010096}
```

In my diploma template I found this line

```
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
```

but I commented it, yet it didnt change anything.

I also found this

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\section*{\refname}%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{}%
       {\leftmargin0pt
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
```

Any ideas?

edit: when I delete that last `\renewenvironment` it looks OK, but I need my Bibliography section not being shown with number in my TOC (red is wrong, green is right):

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With problems like this it would be very helpful for us if you were to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). In your case that could include a bare-bone document with the `\renewenvironment` definition thrown in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so finally I found an answer (it looks like it was fast, but it was after few hours of search)

I changed the 
`\list{}`
to 
`\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}`
in the `\renewenvironment`

Comment: Can you extend the answer to show a full minimal but compilable example?